# Vuforia C# Error: 'ObjectTracker' does not contain a definition for 'RuntimeImageSource'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm following [this tutorial](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/how-to-create-and-load-targets-in-unity.html) on how to create Instant Image Targets at Runtime using **Vuforia**. I've followed every step, but seem to be getting the following error:

```
error CS1061: 'ObjectTracker' does not contain a definition for 'RuntimeImageSource' and no accessible extension method 'RuntimeImageSource' accepting a first argument of type 'ObjectTracker' could be found
```

I've checked to see if the other methods in the `ObjectTracker` class used work, and they work just fine. It just seems to complain about `RuntimeImageSource`, which according to [the documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObjectTracker.html) is a public property of `ObjectTracker`.

Unless the docs are out of date.

Using **Visual Studio**, I inspected the `ObjectTracker` class and got this:

```cs
#region Assembly Vuforia.UnityExtensions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\VuforiaSupport\Managed\Runtime\Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll
#endregion

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Vuforia
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The ObjectTracker encapsulates methods to manage DataSets and provides access
    //     to the ImageTargetBuilder and TargetFinder classes
    public class ObjectTracker : Tracker
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     exposes the ImageTargetBuilder member to other classes
        public ImageTargetBuilder ImageTargetBuilder { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Activates the given dataset. Datasets can only be activated when the tracker
        //     is not running.
        public bool ActivateDataSet(DataSet dataSet);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new empty dataset.
        public DataSet CreateDataSet();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Deactivates the given dataset. This can only be done when the tracker is not
        //     running.
        public bool DeactivateDataSet(DataSet dataSet);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Deactivates the currently active dataset and destroys all datasets
        public void DestroyAllDataSets(bool destroyTrackables);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Destroy the given dataset. Returns false if the given dataset is active.
        public bool DestroyDataSet(DataSet dataSet, bool destroyTrackables);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns the currently activated datasets.
        public IEnumerable<DataSet> GetActiveDataSets();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns all datasets.
        public IEnumerable<DataSet> GetDataSets();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a new Target finder of the specific type
        //
        // Returns:
        //     Instance of TargetFinder
        public TargetFinder GetTargetFinder<T>() where T : TargetFinder;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns all Target Finders.
        public IEnumerable<TargetFinder> GetTargetFinders();
        public override bool Start();
        public override void Stop();
    }
}
```

Which, as you can see, doesn't contain the `RuntimeImageSource` public attribute.

Are the docs out of date? Or is it because I'm using the free version of Vuforia?

I've asked in the Vuforia forum with no answer. I have Googled but found nothing. I can't move forward without it.

Comment: It seems quite obvious that the version you have does not have the RuntimeImageSource you're looking for.. it may have been moved, or altered or you have the wrong verson..

Comment: @BugFinder - Thanks, I have the latest version of Vuforia, maybe it's in an older version. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @BugFinder - I'm such a neewb, you were right.. it was the wrong Vuforia version. I should have seen that coming *facepalm*. Thank you :) been stuck on this for a while.